# Resize the terminal in vscode is trigger the ctrl+c to terminate the running command

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10

I'm running the vscode 1.64.2 on Windows 10. Currently i met a strange problem, When i resize the terminal in the vscode and the cursor is focus on the terminal, Then it will trigger ctrl+c . At this time any running command would be terminated immediately .
To avoid this i have to un-focus for the terminal first and then resize it. Any suggestion here?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching about this with no luck. Today I realized about one installed software on my machine that has a global hook on mouse selection. In my case was the QTranslate software. When I exit the application the problem was solved.
Check if you have this or another software that has a global hook on mouse selection.
In VS Code this problem (control C) was happening for any command line inside the terminal. Apart from that, opening Git bash (standalone) I was having the same issue, but not for cmd or another command line.

Hope this helps you because this was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely working solution!
I experienced the same problem with mouse strange behavior for a long time, but finally I found out it was the QTranslate's guilt! After I stopped it, the problem has gone. (can't vote up because of my virgin profile here).
PS: I found the solution how to push work both QTranslate and terminal window - just set QTranslate setting "Advanced->Copy action" to "Ctrl+Insert" instead of Ctrl+C.